# Time to learn ASP.NET for a client-side scripter?

Tags: asp.net

I am taking part in Imagine Cup and got only three months for building a site in ASP.NET. Is it possible to learn enough to build a working site containing an cms, login system in a month. Its not that I am beginning web development, I already know a little asp.net and know AJAX, JAVASCRIPT, CSS, HTML, SQL but have never worked with databases. I was never into web development but started because of Imagine cup. In 2 months I already know HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, HTML and AJAX but I am worried about the complexity of server-side scripting and ask for the best way to get me working in ASP.NET in a month. I know c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can't be an expert in a month, you can get up and running fairly quickly with webforms. Since it already includes a login system, you can get that up and running quickly.

As far as CMS, it depends what you need. An advanced CMS system is a major undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting going with ASP.NET**
Actually, if you want to re-apply everything you know about creating JS enabled static html sites, you'd have a smoother path using MVC because you don't have to guess what the tag id's are, you don't have to guess what kind of HTML a server side control is going to create, etc.

That said, Jonathan Wood is correct, to just create a page with labels and buttons, Web Forms has fewer concepts you need to learn, but you will find it harder to apply the same techniques that work well with JS + static html.

**Data bases**
If you use SQL Compact, then it is easier to get started because you needn't learn to mess with the numerous things going on with SQL Server (like a security model appropriate for big companies, but not for learners).  Another easy alternative is MS-Access because the "Query by Example (QBE)" query designer is still better than anything that the Visual Studio or SSMS teams ever put together.

Keep in mind that if you use MS-Access, while it will be really easy to learn (more so than SQL Compact), MS-Access uses Jet SQL and has many other differences from SQL Server, where as everything you learn about SQL Compact will apply to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the conditions etc of Imagine cup are, but I strongly recommend to *use an existing CMS* (in particular [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.com)) instead of developing all from scratch. Some advantages are:

- No need to dive into SQL and databases right away
- Building blocks are available (login system) and leverage existing ASP.NET technologies
- Razor can be used instead of xslt which will be a skill you'll be able to apply to pure ASP.NET MVC development later on
- Very friendly and helpful community if you need some help
- Starter kits available - basic web sites can be created easily
- By diving into any detail of the CMS, you'll learn a lot (source code available)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably pick up the basics with a few good books. Sam's, Wrox, APress and O'Reilly are great. You can also check http://www.asp.net/get-started for Microsoft's official tutorials.

You can also download the express versions of Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server. If you want to continue on after the competition I'd strongly recommend you learn database programming on SQL Server 2010 Express. (It'll help you down the road)

Good luck with it.